# How do I update/change my Stack Exchange OpenID information?

Tags: discussion, user-accounts, stack-exchange

I am not sure where to ask this question. I sign in to Stack Exchange services using my Stack Exchange credentials, but I am having trouble finding where I can update my information. Clicking my username on `stackexchange.com` (which would be the intuitive thing to do) takes me to my account overview, but I do not see anything related to updating my account information.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go to your profile here or on another SE site, not stackexchange.com itself, and hit "my logins".  You should see the option to add a new OpenID, as well as an `(x)` beside the old one.  Stackexchange.com looks to have the ability to add logins, but not remove, strangely.

Comment: Ah. I see it now. Thank you. Is there a way to change my Stack Exchange OpenID email address? Or must I delete the old one and then add a new one?

Comment: @iglvzx I believe the email address is how your openid.stackexchange.com account is uniquely identified, so it can't be changed.  You might be able to change the vanity name to something throwaway, and then create a new SE OpenID with the new address and re-use the old vanity name.  I haven't tried it though.

Comment: I would want that vanity URL though.